# Getting paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: key cannot be used for signing in Paramiko while using multithreading

Tags: python, concurrency, python-multithreading, paramiko

I wrote a simple python script to ssh to a machine run some commands and write to csv.
The script and SSH with Paramiko works fine when it's single thread but when I try to use Multithreaded like so:

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as executor:
            future_to_ssh = {executor.submit(ssh_and_run,entry ,ssh_key, current_user): entry for entry in filtered_entries}
            # loop works at 8 workers anymore and it fails
            for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_ssh):
                entry = future_to_ssh[future]
                try:
                    data = future.result()
                except Exception as exc:
                    print('%r generated an exception: %s' % (entry, exc))
                    #sleep to try and solve ssh key problem
                    time.sleep(1)
                else:
                    print('%r page is %d bytes' % (entry, len(data)))
```

I sometimes get an exception of `paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: key cannot be used for signing`

The code that gets the key is outside the loop and looks like that:

```
# Create an SSH agent object
    ssh_agent = paramiko.Agent()

    try:
    # Check if there is at least one key loaded in the SSH agent
        if not ssh_agent.get_keys():
            print("No keys found in SSH agent.")
        
        # Get the first key from the SSH agent
        ssh_key = ssh_agent.get_keys()[0]

    except paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException as e:
        print("Failed to retrieve key from SSH agent:", e)
```

The thing is the loops works for 4/5 workers and sometimes 8 workers but then It will fail once and from then on will not be able to SSH to any other machine.

Q1: Does ssh with paramiko requires me to have a Lock on the ssh_key? I didn’t find any mention on it either on paramiko or concurrent documentation and I admit that I don't know how to debug this Multithreaded code.

Q2: does the number of workers correlate to the number of CPU cores that my machine has? meaning I have 8 cores so i need to put max_workers=8? for this task it is mostly I\O bound so does it matters ?

I tried changing the num of max_workers, more will fail faster hence my suspicions that its the threads somehow ruining the key